# Force fraffic between PPPoE users to pass through traffic management device

Tags: cisco, routing, troubleshooting, pppoe

I would like that traffic between pppoe users passes through a traffic management device as showed below[image]

I have evarything working, i mean, users have ppp session and they have internet access via a default route in the NAS. But traffic between them doesn't pass throught the traffic management device as they are in the same subnet. I tried to configure a PBR for traffic incoming the in-interface with no success

```
access-list 100 permit ip any any
!
route-map toallot permit 10
 match ip address 100
 set ip next-hop X.X.X.1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.1000
 description VLAN_PPPoE
 encapsulation dot1Q 1000
 pppoe enable group PPPOE_SERVER
 ip policy route-map toallot
```

I implemented this on Imagestream Routers but never on Cisco. Is there any other way to achieve this or PBR is the only way ? Anyone could help me to discover what is going wrong with this pbr config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The policy has to be attached to the individual PPP interface(s), i.e. the virtual-template or dialer that's cloned for each virtual-access interface. G0/1.1000 has no IP protocol running on it, so the policy does nothing.

Comment: Thanks! I also attached to the Virtual-Template, I can see the access-list match counter increasing all the time, but even with the default route X.X.X.1 unreachable i still can ping from one ppp user to other.

Comment: I achieve in the lab to do this applying the policy to the virtual template and (as I have many subnets in the router) creted an object-group in order to use it in the ACL. Now we put the router in production and seems tha is not working.